# How to place ImageView half overlapped on top boundary of ConstraintLayout in a Fragment?

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to make a Login screen where my LoginActivity contains a LoginFragment which is used to get user input for display picture, username, and password. Now, I want to display my circular ImageView centered and half-overlapping the top boundary of the ConstraintLayout which is the root Layout of my Fragment (as shown in the attached image). How can I achieve this? Everything is working fine except for the placement of the ImageView. I have also attached the code of my fragment layout xml.

I have already seen [How to half overlap images in android constraint layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49319581/how-to-half-overlap-images-in-android-constraint-layout) and [how to half overlap imageview on another imageview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41587954/how-to-half-overlap-imageview-on-another-imageview-in-android), but none of these achieve the desired result.

Here is the LoginFragment XML

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_card"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:padding="24dp"
    android:layout_margin="24dp">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_profile" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext_username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/tinBlue"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:hint="@string/hint_username"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageview_profile"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:maxLength="20"/>

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/tinBlue"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:hint="@string/hint_password"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/edittext_username"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:maxLength="20"/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_forgot_password"
        android:text="@string/text_forgot_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginVertical="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/edittext_password"/>
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="24dp"
        android:background="@color/tinBlue"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/login_button_label"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textview_forgot_password"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the LoginActivity XML

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                               xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                               android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                               android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                               android:background="@color/darkGray">
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_tin_account"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text_tin_account"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginVertical="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/login_ui_container"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textview_tin_account"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text_new_user"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginVertical="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
```

Here is the required result
[image: Required Result]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mbzze.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can constrain the `ImageView` to the middle of the top edge of your `Fragment` layout as shown in the questions you referenced (you don't need the `Guideline`):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview_profile"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/circle"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
```

Then, allow children to draw outside their bounds by setting `android:clipChildren="false"` and `android:clipToPadding=false` in each of the parent layouts i.e. all the parent `ConstraintLayouts` layouts.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried your solution, but it clips the top half of the ImageView i.e. only the lower half semi-circle is visible. Even setting clipChildren to false in the  fragment root container also results in the same semi-circle. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Is your fragment a direct child of the `LoginActivity's` root `ConstraintLayout`? Could you perhaps add your activity's layout to your post? `android:clipChildren="false"` should be added to whichever `ViewGroup` is hosting the fragment.

Comment: It is contained in a ConstraintLayout which itself is in a ConstraintLayout. I've updated the question. Have a look. And yes, I have also added `android:clipChildren=false` in login_ui_container ConstraintLayout, but it also does the same semi-circle thing.

Comment: So you should add `android:clipChildren="false"` to `id/login_ui_container` `ConstraintLayout`

Comment: How are you adding your fragment to the activity? Your activity layout does not include the fragment.

Comment: I am dynamically adding my fragment to my activity in login_ui_container.